# PHP - generating special unique ID

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so just rewriting the Question - so that you see what i did until now and what my Question really means!

For a Webapplication i am trying to build i need IDs which are 5 characters long. I want to use A-Z and 0-9 for the IDs to have more possible IDs. If there are now 5 character long IDs left - the System should notice it and change to 6 charaters - and so on.

I already know how to build the IDs with the characters I want to use - but my Question is: Is there a better Way to check if the ID is already in use or to ensure that the id can't be in use as doing a recursion between generateID -> try to insert -> on fail -> restart -> ... ?

Comment: Do you have some Ideas? What have you tried? Show some code effort please. If you can't be bothered to google "PHP - generating special unique ID" then neither can I.

Comment: 1. `UNIQUE` index on that column 2. Generate in php 3. Try to insert 4. If fails `goto #2` else `goto #5` 5. It's inserted

Comment: How about a number from 1 to 99999?

Comment: Why not just use autoincrement field for id generation?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, the only way to guarantee uniqueness without checking is to use some function that has a one-to-one mapping to something that is already guaranteed to be unique, such as an existing record ID which your database schema probably already contains. The simplest case I can think of would be to take the hexadecimal representation of such a record ID using `dechex($id)`.

A mapping function that generates a YouTube-like alphanumeric ID from a numeric ID and vice versa is discussed here: [Create Youtube-Like IDs With PHP/Python/Javascript/Java/SQL](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl/)